# Need similar date function in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby

I was trying to explore the Date function in nodejs. When I am  running this function

```
new Date
=> 2017-11-24T06:06:27.215Z
```

I try to do the same thing in rails but couldn't find anything which can give me the same result as in nodejs

```
DateTime.now
 Fri, 24 Nov 2017 11:37:50 +0530 

Time.now
2017-11-24 11:38:02 +0530
```

Both the above thing is not giving me the same thing as in nodejs

Could anyone help me out with this thing

Here is the [link](https://repl.it/repls/FractalWiseAfricanwildcat) where I am testing Date function in node js

Comment: The link: https://repl.it/repls/FractalWiseAfricanwildcat doesn't have the code i guess.

Comment: I don't know about ".215Z" at the end of node generated string but you can do something similar in rails with `Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')` which outputs "2017-11-24T11:50:14+0530".

Comment: This I already know I need the end part(.215Z) in rails

Comment: @user6554447 check my post, you will get seconds upto 3 digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this:

```
[2] pry(main)> require 'time'
=> true
[3] pry(main)> Time.now.utc.iso8601
=> "2017-11-24T06:23:21Z"
[4] pry(main)>
```

The “Z” on the end of the ISO8601 date indicates that it is in UTC, not a local time zone.

and to get finner resolution:

```
[20] pry(main)> Time.now.utc.round(10).iso8601(6)
=> "2017-11-24T06:26:58.008245Z"
```

Comment: ok take a look at the update for get better resolution as in nodoejs, I'm glad thisl help

Answer (score 1):

```
Time.now.utc.iso8601(3)
 => "2017-11-24T06:29:58.187Z"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime.now.iso8601
#⇒ "2017-11-24T07:21:03+01:00"
```

Please note, that one *must* always use time zone in Rails, like `Time.zone.now` otherwise different time zones will ruin the application logic sooner or later. There is a [brilliant blog post](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/) on it for further reference.

Comment: It is still not the exact same result

Comment: You seem to completely misunderstand what format is it and why this differs from your node result.